# How to limit number of threads all concurrent methods at once

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hikaricp, forkjoinpool

I am working on a legacy project which uses Java 8, Spring, HikariCP, and MySQL. Microservices' methods are triggered with a Kafka topic and start a reporting operation. Almost all triggered methods have this and some of them have the same usage inside their blocks.

```java
new ForkJoinPool().submit(() -> { users.parallelStream().forEach(user ->
```

The application creates 8-9k threads and all of them try to get or create a record. However, the database couldn't handle these requests and started to throw exceptions and Zabbix sends mails about heap memory usage above %90:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-2 -
> Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.

When I check the database and see the variable for max_connections = 600, but this is not enough.

I want to set a limit for thread count for the application level.
I tried setting these parameters but the thread size doesn't decrease.

SPRING_TASK_EXECUTION_POOL_QUEUE-CAPACITY , SPRING_TASK_EXECUTION_POOL_MAX-SIZE, -Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism

Is there any property to solve this problem?

Comment: I would say the code is the culprit, fix it. Setting those properties you are setting has no effect on the code as that code isn't using anything spring managed (apart from maybe the `users` whatever that is). What you should do, instead of `new ForkJoinPool()` (which is imho a bad idea anyway) inject an `AsyncTaskExecutor` and use its submit method. You can then use those properties to limit the number of threads created.

Comment: What do you(@M.Deinum) think about change forkjoinpool to this -> "ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(() -> " I think this changes might use this parameter -Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism

Comment: Well that might lead to other issues. What you want, and should prevent, is the creation of a new `ForkJoinPool` for each request, as that will eventually kill your application. As stated using a `TaskExecutor` to fire up those things in the background (as that is what it primarily is the use here). You want a more finegrained control for that I suggested the `TaskExecutor` as that you can configure with some nice threads and a queue size. However without seeing all of your code it will only be general recommendations and not a to the point solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed all `new ForkJoinPool() to ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` and use this parameter to control thread creation `-Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism` after that I have fixed my problem.